# Does mingw gcc ignores CFLAGS?

Tags: gcc, mingw

It seems for me that mingw wersion of gcc ignores CFLAGS environment variable. Am i right? How it could be fixed?

I've done following:

create simple test.c file

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a;
    return 0;
}
```

and run form mingw bash prompt

```
$ export CFLAGS="-Wall"
$ gcc test.c    <-- no warnings
$ gcc test.c -Wall 
$  ... warning: unused variable 'a'
```

Comment: All versions of GCC ignore that environment variable. It's not something the compiler uses.

Comment: Are C compilers supposed to do that? I always assumed CFLAGS was just a Makefile thing, not a compiler thing.

Comment: `gcc -c $CFLAGS test.c` would by convention normally be the command executed by a Makefile. The environment variable is not picked up by the compiler in any way, but `make` can if it chooses to.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker a makefile doesn't necessarily need or requires a variable named CFLAGS in it. CFLAGS it's a **naming** convention for flags for a c compiler, you can use it or not.

Comment: CFLAGS is indeed built in to the default rules in Gmake. It's not just a convention, it's a hard-coded default. If you don't want it, you have to explicitly undefine it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that's because you have an implicit declaration in that case, if you will code a tool to automatically generate some code and you put something hardcoded in it, doesn't mean that you are changing the rules of the compilation, you are just adding something by default.

Comment: Yes, but that's what I meant my "it's a Makefile thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFLAGS` it's not an environment variable required or used by the `gcc` suite, you can find more about gcc and environment variables [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sorry, it seems makefile option